# Find and Replace/Append text in a file using batch or vbs

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, cmd

I have many files of the same name under different sub directories with a delimiter of "}". I want to find a set of specific text and append some new text before the delimiter. For example:

```
folder1\sample.css
    .asd {}
    .bar {}
folder2\sample.css
    .foo {}
    .bar {}
```

All sample.txt files should then look like:

```
..
.foo {display:none;}
..
```

How would I accomplish this using vbs, powershell, or preferably a batch file?
Something similar to this:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /r %%f in (*.txt) do (
    for /f "delims=}" %%a in (%%f) do (
        set str=%%a
        REM modify the variable
        REM replace the line with the variable
    )
)
```

EDIT:
I got it working, but I'm sure this could be written much better with more re-usability.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /r %%f in (index.css) do (
    BatchSubstitute.bat ".foo {" ".foo { display:none;" %%f>%%f.new
    del %%f
    BatchSubstitute.bat ".bar {" ".bar { display:none;" %%f.new>%%f
    del %%f.new
    BatchSubstitute.bat ".asd {" ".asd { display:none;" %%f>%%f.new
    del %%f
    ren %%f.new index.css
)
```

BatchSubstitute.bat

```
@echo off
REM -- Prepare the Command Processor --
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

::BatchSubstitude - parses a File line by line and replaces a substring"
::syntax: BatchSubstitude.bat OldStr NewStr File
::          OldStr [in] - string to be replaced
::          NewStr [in] - string to replace with
::          File   [in] - file to be parsed
:$changed 20100115
:$source http://www.dostips.com
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.
)
```

Comment: CMD is not a good match for this. I suggest you use whichever of VBS and Powershell you are more familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize this batch file: http://www.dostips.com/?t=Batch.FindAndReplace

Make a call to that inside your loop of files in which you seek find/replace of `.foo {}` with `.foo{display:none;}`.

There are probably better find/replace binaries than using this find/replace batch, but it'll probably do the job.